# Is it right to identify a reusable cell using NSObject's hash property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a NSMutableArray of custom objects and for each of them I want to display appropriate row in UITableView. The array will keep changing and so the TableView, obviously. My objects don't maintain any unique identifier, so I was wondering how can I identify them within `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method for further reuse.

Would it be a good approach to use object's `hash` property, as shown below?

```
MyGroup *group = groups[indexPath.row];
NSString *reuseId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"group_id_%d", group.hash];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseId];
if (cell == nil) {
    // ... init cell ...
}
```

I think a special scenario can occur when I remove some objects from `groups` array and then add a different object which happens to have the same hash as one of the removed ones. That would mess up rendering, since UITableView would reuse the old cell created for object that doesn't exist anymore.

Is this concern legitimate? Is there any other (reliable) way of identifying object instances using string value that would remain unique during application lifetime?

Comment: You're using a lot of terms like "appropriate," "good," "legitimate" and "reliable" that are highly subjective.  What do you want, specifically and objectively?

Comment: I want to give each cell a unique string ID that would identify its linked object in NSMutableArray. I was thinking about using object's hash, but I'm not sure if that's unique enough during application lifetime and can't possibly lead to clash.

Comment: Your proposed use of cell identifier is completely inappropriate. That is not at all what it is used for.

Comment: You should try to explain what results you are after. It appears you are not clear on what a cell reuse id is for. Typically it is used to get a different subclass of UITableViewCell for displaying different data types. For instance, I may have a table with tree cells and bug cells. I would then have 2 reuse ids, one for tree cells and one for bug cells. This does not appear to be the case in your situation, but I cannot quite tell what you are after.

Comment: Do you have an array of completely unique objects and want to link a different object to a unique, custom row? Or are you trying to create a way to access the model object from the cell?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, as you mentioned, my understanding of cell identifiers was indeed wrong. I thought each cell must be uniquely identified in order to prevent rendering errors, that's why the question about hash uniqueness. Went through Apple docs and it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** I misunderstood the concept of reusable cell identifiers. Every cell doesn't need to have unique reuse identifier, in fact it's wrong to do so, as it would prevent UITableView from reusing cells.